# Silverlight Smooth Streaming Client Memory Usage

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, memory-management

The sample Smooth Streaming Client provided [here](http://blogs.iis.net/vsood/archive/2009/10/14/building-your-first-smooth-streaming-player.aspx) continues to grow in memory until it fails out with an Out of Memory Exception.  Our version is using Silverlight 3 and we have tried the Beta 2 and TRW 1 versions of the [Smooth Streaming Client](http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothClient).  However, the memory usage continues to be a problem.

There are numerous values to control the buffers in the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.smoothstreamingmediaelement%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) like FlushBuffers, but none of them seem to affect the memory usage.

Using WinDbg, I see that there are giant System.Byte arrays and System.UInt, but I can't seem to clear them out.

Any thoughts as to how I can clear the buffers or chunks to keep the memory usage more reasonable?